# Can not call setState out of componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I alway got message:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Admin
>   component.

When I using `setState` outside `componentDidMount` function.

This is my source code:

```
class Admin extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mainModal: false,
            itemId: null,
            bulkRemove: true,
            params: {},
            defaultRole: null,
            dataLoaded: store.getState().adminReducer.list.length?true:false
        };
        this.list = this.list.bind(this);
        this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
        this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this);
        this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckAll = this.handleCheckAll.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);

        this.filterTimeout = null;
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        ...
        this.list();
        // this.setState({dataLoaded: true}); // OK when call here
        ...
    }

    list(outerParams={}, page=1){
        let params = {
           page
        };

        if(!isEmpty(outerParams)){
            params = {...params, ...outerParams};
        }

        Tools.apiCall(apiUrls.list, params, false).then((result) => {
            if(result.success){
                console.log(this);
                // output of above console.log -> Admin {props: Object, context: undefined, refs: Object, updater: Object, state: Object…}
                // this.setState({dataLoaded: true}); // Error when call here or inside setInitData function
                this.setInitData(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I use babel preset `es2015` then everything ok, but same error with `es2016` or `es2017`.

Comment: What is calling your `list()` method, and what's the state of the component when it's called? The error message is basically telling you you've called it on an uninitialized component - you've called `setState()` before 'state' has been defined.

Comment: I called in inside componentDidMount function. I think inside this, the component has been initialized.

Comment: Ah ha - sorry, I missed that. Did you bind `this.list` in your constructor? Methods on react components don't auto-bind, so `this` may no longer be what you think it is by the time you're accessing it.

Comment: I've update the code. I had bind this.list function in constructor. When I console.log(this) inside list() function. I got the correct component but still can not setState.